# MySQL driver for EF6 returns wrong identity after insert

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, mysql.data

I am using EF6 and MySQL.Data v6.9.5 to connect to a MySQL database. When I insert a record, call db.SaveChanges() and reference the record's ID column, I get what looks like a valid ID, but for some reason the ID will change in the database.

Sample Code

```
var res = db.SampleRegs.Add(sample);
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            //now, to fire a trigger, we need to UPDATE the table and set Saved = 10; (trigger fires on UPDATE when Saved = 10).
            db.Entry(res).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            //Now set Saved = 20 to fire another trigger
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);//because reasons
            res.Saved = sbyte.Parse("20");
            db.Entry(res).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When I put a breakpoint on `res` the ID field would e.g. have a value of 128990. But when I later inspect the MySQL table directly, it will have a different ID value, which seems to always be 100 to 200 less, e.g. 12880.

I have no idea what's going on here because I can't replicate this behaviour in our development and testing environment db's, but when I move to production, this happens. I know the production DB handles a large volume of data in the specific table, if that matters at all.

Comment: What's this trigger for? This sounds like the database generating an ID value, while EF queries the wrong generated ID because generating and querying the ID doesn't happen in one scope/session.

Comment: the trigger adds records to other tables. The record I am inserting isn't normalised, so there are literally 400 fields that need to be migrated to other related tables (I am not the architect).